Combination of abstract classes and generics problem when declaring and instantiating
I am struggling with an app in C# that is a document review app that searches documents for a list of search terms. It needs to either take a PDF or WORD document and possibly others in the future.
I have an enum DocumentType:
public enum DocumentType
{
    NotSpecified,
    PDF,
    WORD

}

and a base class DocumentInterface<DocumentType>:
public abstract class DocumentInterface<DocumentType>
{

    private string _documentPath;
    private readonly DocumentType _document;
    private int _pageCount;
    private int _currentPage;
    
    // Path to the document being reviewed
    public string DocumentPath
    {
        get { return _documentPath; }
        set { _documentPath = value; }
    }
    
    // Document Object will need to be typecast in child classes
    public abstract DocumentType Document { get; set; }
    //{
    //  get { return _document; }
    //  set { _document = value; }
    //}
    
    // Count of pages in the review document
    public int PageCount
    {
        get { return _pageCount; }
        set { _pageCount = value; }
    }
    
    // to keep track of where we are up to in the document
    public int CurrentPage
    {
        get { return _currentPage; }
        set { _currentPage = value; }
    }
    
    // reports if there are any more pages after the current position.
    public bool HasMorePages { get { return _currentPage < _pageCount; } }
    
    
    public string GetNextPageContents()
    {
        // Makes sure that there is a next page and if so then uses the abstract method
        // to return the page contents.
        if (HasMorePages)
        {
            _currentPage++;
            return GetPageContents(_currentPage);
        }
                
        return string.Empty;
    }
    
    
    #region Constructor & Destructor
    
    public DocumentInterface(string documentpath)
    {
        _document = OpenDocument(documentpath);
    
        // Make sure we opened the document successfully
        if (_document != null)
        {
            _pageCount = GetPageCount();
            _currentPage = 0;
        }
    }
    
    // Class Destructor, must close the document when going out of scope.
    ~DocumentInterface()
    {
        // Abstract method, must be implemented by child classes.
        CloseDocument();
    }
    
    #endregion
    
    
    #region Abstract Methods
    
    // Abstract Class must be implemented by Document Type specific child classes
    public abstract DocumentType OpenDocument(string path);
    public abstract int GetPageCount();
    public abstract string GetPageContents(int pageNumber);
    public abstract void CloseDocument();
    
    #endregion

}

and a derived class DocumentInterfacePDF:
public class DocumentInterfacePDF : DocumentInterface<PdfDocument>
{
    // Implementation of the abstract base generic as a PdfDocument
    private PdfDocument _document;

    public override PdfDocument Document 
    { 
        get => (PdfDocument)_document; 
        set => _document = value as PdfDocument; 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="documentpath"></param>
    /// <exception cref="Exception"></exception>
    public override PdfDocument OpenDocument(string documentpath)
    {
        if (// All need to be true!                
            documentpath != null
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(documentpath)
            && ".pdf" == documentpath.Substring(documentpath.Length - 4).ToLower()
            )
        {
            // Open the PDF
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(documentpath);

            // return to base class to assign to _document
            return new PdfDocument(reader);
        }
        return null;
    }

    #region Base Class Overrides to implement as a iText7 PDF Interface

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of pages in the PDF document
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override int GetPageCount()
    {
        // Return the Page Count
        return Document.GetNumberOfPages();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the page contents for a specific page number
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pageNumber"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string GetPageContents(int pageNumber)
    {
        // Set the default scanning extents for the PDF Reader
        // numbers are points which are 72 to the inch
        int A4_width  = 595;    // 210mm
        int A4_height = 842;    // 297mm
        int header    =  57;    //  20mm
        int footer    =  57;    //  20mm
        var rect = new Rectangle(0, header, A4_width, A4_height - footer);

        PdfPage page = Document.GetPage(pageNumber);

        // Read the page contents
        FilteredTextEventListener listener =
                new FilteredTextEventListener(
                new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(),
                new TextRegionEventFilter(rect)
                );

        // Return the page contents
        return PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, listener);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the PDF Document
    /// </summary>
    public override void CloseDocument()
    {
        // Close the document
        Document.Close();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// Call the base class constructor to setup everything in the predefined way.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="documentpath"></param>
    public DocumentInterfacePDF(string documentpath) : base(documentpath)
    {
        // all of the implementation is taken care of in the Base Class
    }

    #endregion
}

In my DocumentParser class I want to instantiate the document using the base class so that the derived type can be decided at runtime depending on the document type that the user selects.
internal class ReviewDocumentParser
{
    #region Properties

    private List<SearchTerm> _searchterms;
    private SearchResults _results;
    private string _documentPath;
    private string _searchTermsPath;
    private DocumentInterface<DocumentType> _documentInterface;

    public List<SearchTerm> SearchTerms
    {
        get { return _searchterms; }
        set { _searchterms = value; }
    }

    public SearchResults Results
    {
        get { return _results; }
        set { _results = value; }
    }

    public string DocumentPath
    {
        get { return _documentPath; }
        set { _documentPath = value; }
    }

    public string SearchTermsPath
    {
        get { return _searchTermsPath; }
        set { _searchTermsPath = value; }
    }

    private DocumentType _documentType;

    public DocumentType DocumentType
    {
        get { return _documentType; }
        set { _documentType = value; }
    }

    public DocumentInterface<DocumentType> DocumentInterface
    {
        get { return _documentInterface; }
        set { _documentInterface = value; }
    }

    #endregion

//... unnecessary code ommitted

    #region Constructor

    public ReviewDocumentParser(DocumentType documenttype, string documentpath, string searchtermspath)
    {
        _documentType = documenttype;
        _documentPath = documentpath;
        _searchTermsPath = searchtermspath;

        // Hook the Search Terms element up
        _results = new SearchResults(_searchTermsPath);

        switch (documenttype)
        {
            case DocumentType.PDF:
                _documentInterface = new DocumentInterfacePDF(_documentPath);
                break;
            case DocumentType.WORD:
                _documentInterface = new DocumentInterfaceWORD(_documentPath);
                break;
            case DocumentType.NotSpecified:
                throw new NoDocumentParserFoundException("No suitable document parser found.");
        }
    }

    #endregion

I'm trying to resolve the following error with no luck, I'm going round and round in circles replacing one problem with another. I'm starting to think I am trying to do something that isn't doable. I've been at a standstill for 24 hours now.

Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'PDF_Reader_Test.Model.DocumentInterfacePDF' to 'PDF_Reader_Test.Model.DocumentInterface'

I've tried adding a type descriptor to the instantiation statement(s). PdfDocument is a type defined in the iText7 package that I am using to extract the text only from PDF documents.
case DocumentType.PDF:
    _documentInterface = new DocumentInterfacePDF<PdfDocument>(_documentPath);
    break;

But this just generates a different warning. I've also tried modifying the base and derived class definitions but I am just hitting bigger problems, I think they are (almost) right as they are.
I was expecting the base class to be able to have a derived class type assigned to it. I am wanting to define the broad behaviour in the base class so it is consistent and just override the bits that handle the different file types within the derived classes for PDF and Word. I haven't tackled the Word version yet.

Unrelated: Do not call a class "DocumentInterface".

Also, but really critical: do not rely on destructors! Use IDisposable instead.

In your DocumentInterface<T> base class,  DocumentType is your T generic type. In your parser, DocumentType is your enum DocumentType. And your DocumentInterfacePDF is-a DocumentInterface<T>, not a DocumentInterace<DocumentType>.

Thanks for the response.
Noted about using "Interface" in the class name... I did think about this but couldn't come up with anything better at the time, I'll give this another thought.
I've never implemented anything using IDisposable before, but thanks for the pointer, I'll do some research.
I think I follow your logic. I'll give this a go. So I'm on the right track then...? This isn't something that just isn't possible...?
Many Thanks @Fildor

Thanks for the help so far... I've renamed my DocumentInterface class to DocumentHelper, DocumentHelperPDF etc... I've also converted to using IDisposable, who knew it was so easy (I'm relatively new to a lot of this). I've done a bit more reading up on using Generics and I think I have a better idea, and managed to untangle a lot of it already and cleared a heap of the errors that I was getting myself back into by hacking around with the code.

As far as parsing the PDF file, I've got that sorted, I'm using the iText7 package and it's allowing me to pull out plain text which I am then also managing to search and find single and multi word search terms which is the result I'm after. Thanks again for the help

So, there's several issues here, some were already mentioned in the comments.

Naming conventions: Don't call your base class "interface". It's not an interface, and interfaces are typically prefixed with "I". a better choice would be simply Document or possibly DocumentBase. Also, it is common practice to prefex generic parameters with T, so a better choice might be: class DocumentBase<TDocument>.

Disposing: As a rule of thumb, don't rely on finalizers (destructors). Your class should implement IDisposable. Then, if your underlying implementation[s] (e.g. PdfDocument) need disposing, you should do so in the Dispose() method.

ReviewDocumentParser: It's bad design to do all the expensive IO and document loading inside the constructor. Either, make the document not part of the parser's state, but create a method that returns the document implementation, or put the logic into a factory method.


To directly address your problem: You are using DocumentType both as a type name, and as the name for your generic parameter, which is unlucky, because now you have accidentially declared DocumentInterface<DocumentType> _documentInterface with the enum type as generic argument, that is why you cannot assign DocumentInterfacePDF which has PdfDocument as generic argument.
As you see, that's how conforming to proper naming conventions protects you against such mistakes.
Furthermore, I would argue that you probably don't even need the generic parameter in the first place. You could keep that as an implementation detail of the derived type.
Here's a simplified version how I might approach this. (Disclaimer: I am not familiar with itext, so it's only about the class design.)
public abstract class Document : IDisposable
{
    public abstract int PageCount { get; }
    
    public abstract string GetPageContents(int pageNumber);
    
    // [...]

    public abstract void Dispose();
}

public sealed class PdfDocument : Document
{
    // full namespace to avoid name collisions
    private readonly iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader _reader;
    private readonly iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument _document;
    private bool _disposed;
    
    public PdfDocument(string path)
    {
        // (maybe you want to put this into a static factory method)
        _reader = new (path);
        _document = new (_reader);
    }
    
    public override int PageCount => _document.GetNumberOfPages();

    public override string GetPageContents(int pageNumber)
    {
        // [...]
        return null;
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }
        _document.Close();
        _reader.Close();
        _disposed = true;
    }
}

internal class ReviewDocumentParser
{
    public Document Parse(DocumentType documenttype, string documentpath, string searchtermspath)
    {
        // [...]
        switch (documenttype)
        {
            case DocumentType.PDF:
                return new PdfDocument(_documentPath);
                break;
            // [...]
        }
        return null;
    }
}


Thanks for the help and also going to the trouble of coding a part explanation. I've removed the word Interface from my class name now and and its now DocumentHelper, DocumentHelperPDF etc. I've also looked into using IDispose and implemented that as well... I've seen it used in other libraries, but didn't realise how straightforward it was to use it.

Appreciate the comments about doing the work in the constructor, and also the suggestion to not overcomplicate the superclass by storing the document. I was hoping to enforce a standardized approach to implementing any subclasses in the future, but possibly overcomplicating things. I know I was confusing myself with the naming in the ENUM DocumentType too Really so might re-engineer that. This is just a prototype at the moment, so opportunities to address a lot of this... and a nice learning opportunity. appreciate the help @Marsze

I still have one outstanding issue, in trying to instantiate a property of the base class in my my program I am getting an error when trying to use
private DocumentHelper _documentHelper;
The error is Using the generic type 'DocumentHelper' requires type 1 argument and if I change it to this
private DocumentHelper<T> _documentHelper;
then it obviously doesn't recognise 'T'

@IanJames You will need a specific type as generic argument when declaring the field. Either get rid of the generic parameter altogether, as I suggested, or make a non-generic base class.

Thanks... that's helpful, I think I was confusing the document and the functionality because it is conveniently wrapped up in the iText implementation, but its starting to make a it more sense now... thanks again ;)

Personally I try to hide the fact given type implements IDisposable (using factory method/type) but adding it right to public base type is worse than adding it to "end" type. For all reasons valid to exposing it in the first place and additionally for forcing to implement it types that does not need it (and this to leads to questions like "Do I really need to dispose MemoryStream" or wondering "When can I omit disposing TaskCancellationSource"). Operation and cleaning concerns are better to be kept separated.

@greenoldman Then how would the consumer know it should be disposed? If most derived types are likely to need disposing (such as Stream), the base type should show that. Having an empty default impl in the base or unnecessary dispose calls is absolutely fine compared to the risk of leaving objects undisposed. This would only be acceptable in scenarios where lifetime is managed automatically (like HttpClient or DI).

@marsze Factory method/types returns tuple (pair actually) -- the interface or base type or something along those lines (like Document above) and IDisposable. The second one does not have necessarily be the same object as the first one -- it could be additional actions packed within it. It is especially handy if you chain-create stuff, you simply pack, and pack more stuff into this second IDisposable.

@greenoldman I have never seen that design anywhere. Going just from that short description, it sounds like a bad idea. Either way, I doubt it applies in the particular use case of this question. However, feel free to create your own answer with an alternative approach and I'll have a look at it.

@marsze After some years of using it the only downside I see is it is not widespread :-) Especially it is pain/risk when using together with MS DI, which is disaster on its own. Maybe it would be a good point to write a longer post about it and rationale.

@marsze I am glad I wrote it "a bit" later because meanwhile I solved the problem I was struggling with, here is the post: https://przypadkopis.wordpress.com/2024/06/15/are-we-condemned-to-inheriting-idisposable/

@greenoldman I think your approach suffers from the very same problems it's trying to solve, while creating some new ones. But that goes beyond what I can write in a comment.
